# Incompatibility with align and table option in xcolor?

Tags: tables, color, align

Let's see this MWE, painfully reduced from an institution template. It chokes on the `align` environment, *unless* I comment out the `table` option in the `xcolor` package. I would like to understand why... and know if there is a workaround, given that the call to `xcolor` is *into* the institution template...

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,hyperref
    ,table  %%% comment this and all works
    ]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%55

\newcommand{\twosidescontent}[3][0.65]{%
    \noindent\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}m{#1\linewidth}c@{}}
        {#2} 
        &
        {\parbox[c][][c]{0.95\linewidth-#1\linewidth}{#3}}
    \end{tabular*}%
}
\begin{document}

\twosidescontent[0.7]{
    Given that 0.3~V is quite a low voltage, let's check with OFF state. 
    The check needed is just $V_{BE}<V_{BE_\mathit{on}}$:
    \[ V_{BE} = 0.3 - 0 = 0.3 < 0.7  \]
    which means it's effectively off. The result will be 
    \begin{align*}
        V_1 &= 0  \\ 
        I_1 &= 0
    \end{align*}
}{ 
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image} %
}

\end{document}
```

It will give an error on the `align*` environment:

```
./p.tex:35: Misplaced \omit.
\math@cr@@@ ...@ \@ne \add@amps \maxfields@ \omit 
                                                  \kern -\alignsep@ \iftag@ ...
l.35 }

./p.tex:35: Misplaced \omit.
\math@cr@@@ ...@ \@ne \add@amps \maxfields@ \omit 
                                                  \kern -\alignsep@ \iftag@ ...
l.35 }
```

And then continue producing the correct output (as far as I can see).

[image: Output after continuing]

If I comment the `table` option in `xcolor` it works.

**The question**: It is possible to have the `align*` environment working **with** the `table` option in `xcolor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what's the problem, but you're approaching the matter from the wrong point of view. `;-)`

You just need no `tabular*` environment.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,hyperref,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%55

\newcommand{\twosidescontent}[3][0.65]{%
  \noindent\parbox{#1\linewidth}{#2}\hfill
  \parbox[c][][c]{0.95\linewidth-#1\linewidth}{#3}%
}
\begin{document}

\twosidescontent[0.7]{
    Given that 0.3~V is quite a low voltage, let's check with OFF state. 
    The check needed is just $V_{BE}<V_{BE_\mathit{on}}$:
    \[ V_{BE} = 0.3 - 0 = 0.3 < 0.7  \]
    which means it's effectively off. The result will be 
    \begin{align*}
        V_1 &= 0  \\ 
        I_1 &= 0
    \end{align*}
}{ 
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image} %
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep. Obvious. What is the emoticon of "banging the head to the wall?". Thanks.